# How to stop and start Appium server programmatically using Java?

Tags: java, appium

How can I perform launching and stopping my server using Java code? Currently I am doing this process manually.

Comment: Refer my blog link - http://happyautomation.blogspot.in/2015/01/how-to-start-stop-appium-server.html

Comment: i reffered ur blog it is showing errors    ---- Starting appium server ----
---- Appium server started Successfully ! ----
'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
---- Stoping appium server ----
---- Appium server stopped Successfully ! ----
ERROR: The process "node.exe" not found.

Comment: Keep your Appium folder D or E drive or C drive.

Comment: @Shekhar Swami installed on c drive only

Comment: If you install appium at C:\Program Files (x86) or C:\Program Files , then java code will throw an error.Cut paste your Appium set up directory at root folder so path will be C:\Appium\... or D:\Appium\.. If you do this  'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, error won't come. If you are still facing issue then please post your code and error

Comment: @RPresle I have installed node.js and appium. Then i have started Appuim server manually. I executed my code which has all desired capabilities. This works fine. But, my issue is, I am starting the Appium server manually before i execute any test cases. and stop it after test finishes. I want the starting and stopping of the appium server should also happen automatically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 3 ways to achieve the scenario.
1)Using AppiumDriverLocalService

```
public void startServer() {
    //Set Capabilities
    cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability("noReset", "false");

    //Build the Appium service
    builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
    builder.withIPAddress("127.0.0.1");
    builder.usingPort(4723);
    builder.withCapabilities(cap);
    builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE);
    builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL,"error");

    //Start the server with the builder
    service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
    service.start();
}

public void stopServer() {
    service.stop();
}
```

2)Using Appium.js with Node.exe

```
public void startServer() {
    CommandLine cmd = new CommandLine("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node.exe");
    cmd.addArgument("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\bin\\Appium.js");
    cmd.addArgument("--address");
    cmd.addArgument("127.0.0.1");
    cmd.addArgument("--port");
    cmd.addArgument("4723");

    DefaultExecuteResultHandler handler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
    executor.setExitValue(1);
    try {
        executor.execute(cmd, handler);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stopServer() {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        runtime.exec("taskkill /F /IM node.exe");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

3)Start Appium server using Command Prompt

```
public void startServer() {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        runtime.exec("cmd.exe /c start cmd.exe /k \"appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723 --session-override -dc \"{\"\"noReset\"\": \"\"false\"\"}\"\"");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stopServer() {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        runtime.exec("taskkill /F /IM node.exe");
        runtime.exec("taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}<br/>
```

I found it helpful.Hope it helps.
Source: http://www.automationtestinghub.com/3-ways-to-start-appium-server-from-java/

Comment: Sometimes, service.stop() fails to stop the execution. We can also kill the specific port from command line right?

Answer (score 2):

For anybody reading this who happens to be using npm (node/js/typescript), I've created a module called [appium-controller](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium-controller) that starts and stops appium in the background programmatically (mac or windows).

Answer (score 2):

The **AppiumDriverLocalService** solution provided on top, solved my never ending issue with **Socket Hang Up** error that I kept receiving when I was starting the server manually.

This is how it looks in my code:

```
public final class AppiumServiceProvider {

    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AppiumServiceProvider.class);
    private static AppiumDriverLocalService service = null;
    private static final TestConfiguration testConfiguration = new TestConfiguration();

    private AppiumServiceProvider() {
    }

    public static AppiumDriverLocalService getService() {
        if (service == null) {
            initAppiumService();
        }
        if (service == null) {
            fail("Cannot start Appium Driver Local Service.");
        }
        return service;
    }

    private static void initAppiumService() {
        Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>(System.getenv());
        env.put("PATH", "/usr/local/bin:" + env.get("PATH"));
        env.put("ANDROID_HOME", "/Users/nets/Library/Android/sdk");

        service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder()
                .usingAnyFreePort()
                .withAppiumJS(new File(testConfiguration.getAppiumJsLocation()))
                .usingDriverExecutable(new File("C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"))
                .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE)
                .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL, "error")
                .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.RELAXED_SECURITY)
                .withEnvironment(env)
                .withLogFile(new File("target/appium.log"))
                .withStartUpTimeOut(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

        log.info("New Appium service: " + service.getUrl());
        service.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read this - it will explain how to start https://github.com/appium/java-client/pull/240

The latest java client has api to do this.

here is one way of starting programetically, the page lists more such ways.

```
        AppiumDriverLocalService service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();
        final DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        // capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Browser");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "MiPad");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName","Appium");
        //            capabilities.setCapability("avd","firstavd");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".ui.activity");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(service, capabilities);
```

Comment: when i use the above lines, i got following Throw-able exception                              
    "org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator "
could you please suggest what i am missing here?

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.4.1 - download the jar and add it .. it has a dependancy on this jar

Answer (score 0):

Try This - it worked for me

Sample Code:

```
public static AppiumDriverLocalService startAppiumServer() {
    boolean flag=   checkIfServerIsRunnning(4723);
    if(!flag)
    {
        AppiumServiceBuilder serviceBuilder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
        // Use any port, in case the default 4723 is already taken (maybe by another Appium server)
        serviceBuilder.usingAnyFreePort();
        // Tell serviceBuilder where node is installed. Or set this path in an environment variable named NODE_PATH
        serviceBuilder.usingDriverExecutable(new File("/Users/Puneetha/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.1/bin/node"));
        // Tell serviceBuilder where Appium is installed. Or set this path in an environment variable named APPIUM_PATH
        serviceBuilder.withAppiumJS(new File("/Users/Puneetha/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.1/bin/appium"));
        // The XCUITest driver requires that a path to the Carthage binary is in the PATH variable. I have this set for my shell, but the Java process does not see it. It can be inserted here.
        HashMap<String, String> environment = new HashMap();
        environment.put("PATH", "/usr/local/bin:" + System.getenv("PATH"));
        serviceBuilder.withEnvironment(environment);

        service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(serviceBuilder);
        service.start();
    }
    return service;
}
```

Comment: Please add explanations to how you address what problem and format the answer properly.

Comment: https://appiumpro.com/editions/71-starting-an-appium-server-programmatically-using-appiumservicebuilder